# PHPExcel create formula from tokens

Tags: phpexcel

how to rebuild formula from tokens

Ex:

```
$formulaParser = new \PHPExcel_Calculation_FormulaParser('=IF(T1<X2,"foo", T1+X2)');
dump($formulaParser->getTokens());
```

I receive:

[image: screenshot at 2016-02-26 10 28 29]

And I modify more value, ex: change `X2` to `T2` and now I need rebuild tokens to formula

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Tokenising a formula is a part of the parsing process, prior to execution of the formula; it's not intended as a method for changing a formula in any way; it's not intended to be reversible

Comment: If you need to change the formula, do it using the string value of that formula, using str_replace() or regexp (or similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tokenising a formula is a part of the parsing process, prior to execution of the formula; it's not intended as a method for changing a formula in any way; it's not intended to be reversible. - Mark Baker

So manually implement by replace string or implode array tokens like

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/834#issuecomment-189158280